# refresh page with ajax jquery without use of reload function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am performing delete records by using jquery ajax in php. I want to refresh that content without the use of location.reload() function. I tried this,

```
$("#divSettings").html(this);
```

but, it's not working. What's the correct logic to get updated content in div.
Thanks.

Code:

```
function deletePoll(postId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../internal_request/ir_display_polls.php",
        data: {
          postId: postId
        },
        success: function(result) {
            location.reload();
            //$("#divSettings").html(this);
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: You would use `$('#divSettings').html(result);`, so long as your `ir_display_polls.php` page returns the proper html.

Comment: You're using `this` when you should be using `result`. Html needs to be updated with the result

Comment: what is the `result` you receive? html?

Comment: result is not giving me latest update after delete the record.....

Comment: Then you have to return the latest update so it's in `result`.

Comment: That will work if, I want to add new record to the id. But, In this case I am deleting the record.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
function deletePoll(postId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../internal_request/ir_display_polls.php",
        data: {
          postId: postId
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#divSettings").html(result); // <-- result must be your html returned from ajax response
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: I tried that one.. But it's not reload the content.. After deleting record. it's still showing previous content until I am not refreshing the page manually.....

Comment: What does `console.log($("#divSettings"));` log? Whats the response of `../internal_request/ir_display_polls.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to set the result into your '#divSettings' element using the .html() function :

```
 $('#divSettings').html(result);
```

So a full example would look like :

```
function deletePoll(postId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../internal_request/ir_display_polls.php",
        data: {
          postId: postId
        },
        success: function(result) {
            //Sets your content into your div
            $('#divSettings').html(result);            
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: I tried that one.. But it's not reload the content.. After deleting record. it's still showing previous content until I am not refreshing the page manually.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to clear the section first and then you can attach the HTML again. Like

```
function deletePoll(postId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../internal_request/ir_display_polls.php",
        data: {
          postId: postId
        },
        success: function(result) {
            //Sets your content into your div
            $('#divSettings').html("");
            $('#divSettings').html(result);            
        }
     });
}
```

I believe this way you won't see the old content.